# API automation testing for localized languages

Tags: api, testing, automation

I am new to api automation and trying to understand few things. I have a web application and it has its APIs exposed for all basic functionality. But this product is also localized in other foreign languages.

My understanding:
The same APIs are used for all languages. APIs actually test functionality and not the UI. For most cases I need not test these APIs again for other languages.

My question:
Is it possible that there would be separate APIs exposed for different locales?
Or can I pass different locale(foreign language) strings as parameters to the same APIs?

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's not the best practice to expose the various API for the different locales. The API that affected from the language may includes the language id. In this case the internal code may take in the consideration the different languages. Then you have to provide in your tests some variations of such language id.

Other case that you have to consider, the API that includes the strings as the parameter.  In this case you will test the strings written in the different languages . Especially you should take in the account the Asia languages like Japanese and Chinese and right to left languages like Arabic and Hebrew.